# How to debug play framework with sbt/eclipse

Tags: playframework, sbt

Reading the doc, it looks pretty easy to do that.  I should only need to start the application with

```
sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

But, I do have this error message :

```
[info] Loading settings for project play-java-ebean-example-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from D:\play\play-java-ebean-example\project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to play-java-ebean-example (in build file:/D:/play/play-java-ebean-example/)
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Not a valid command: -
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected '--'
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Expected 'warn'
[error] Expected 'error'
[error] Expected 'addPluginSbtFile'
[error] -jvm-debug 9999 run
[error]  ^
[INFO] [12/30/2018 17:19:45.858] [Thread-3] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
```

- Play : Version 2.6.x
- SBT : Version 1.0
- OS : Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I added the following line

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
```

in the file

```
sbtconfig.txt
```

And simply start the application with

```
sbt run
```

You`ll see the trace :

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
```

Comment: what is incredible in each version of play i worked never something worked directly ^^